# Give result (either 1 or 2) based on following row in r

Tags: r

I have a table with two rows in my table. The first row will always be "NA" and the second row will always be either a 1 or a 2. I would like to check if the second row is a 1 or 2 and change the "NA" row to be the opposite. Example below:

Table 1:

```
ID   Team
100   NA
101   2
```

Desired result 1:

```
ID   Team
100    1
101    2
```

Table 2:

```
ID   Team
100   NA
101   1
```

Desired result 2:

```
ID   Team
100    2
101    1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have just two rows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(100,101),Team=c(NA,2))

df1$Team[1] <- ifelse(df1$Team[2]==1,2,1)

   ID Team
1 100    1
2 101    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to impute the missing value.

```
library(dplyr)

fill_fun <- function(dt){
  dt <- dt %>%
    mutate(Team = ifelse(is.na(Team) &  nth(Team, 2) == 2, 1,
                         ifelse(is.na(Team) & nth(Team, 2) == 1, 2, Team)))
  return(dt)
}

fill_fun(dt1)
   ID Team
1 100    1
2 101    2

fill_fun(dt2)
   ID Team
1 100    2
2 101    1
```

**Data**

```
dt1 <- read.table(text = "ID   Team
100   NA
                 101   2",
                 header = TRUE)

dt2 <- read.table(text = "ID   Team
100   NA
                  101   1",
                  header = TRUE)
```